# Why `Density plot` peak value is higher than 1?

Tags: r, density-function

Why the peak of density plot in the data given below is higher than 1?  Shouldn't it be below 1?

```
x = c(0.43,0.71,0.6,0.56,0.14,0.38,0.71,0.33,0.09,0.8,0.62,0.33,0.12,0.6,0.4,0.56,0.33,0.75,0.4,0.43,0.75,0.75,0.12,0.09,0.54,1,0.46,0.33,0.33,1,0.5,0.52,1,0.25,0.2,0.71,0.6,0.54,0.75,0.67,0.2,0,0.33,0.73,0.4,0.5,0.56,0.83,0.67,0.6)

plot(density(x))
```

When I multiply all the values by 10 or 100 using `plot(density(x*10))`, the peak is below 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Density is not a probability.  Instead, the probability of a data being in a given range is the area under the density curve.